# Oracle: Fastest way of doing stats on millions of rows?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design

I have developed an application which allows users to enter measurements - these are stored in an Oracle database. Each measurement "session" could contain around 100 measurements. There could be around 100 measurement sessions in a "batch", so that's 10,000 measurements per batch. There could easily be around 1000 batches at some point, bringing the total number of measurements into the millions.

The problem is that calculations and statistics need to be performed on the measurements. It ranges from things like average measurements per batch to statistics across the last 6 months of measurements.

My question is: is there any way that I can make the process of calculating these statistics faster? Either through the types of queries I'm running or the structure of the database?

Thanks!

Comment: The 2 main tables at this time are MEASUREMENTS which contains all of the measurements, and MEASUREMENT_SESSIONS which contains summary data e.g. start time and end time of each session of measurements.

Comment: Have you got appropriate indexes and looked at individual queries and used `EXPLAIN PLAN` to check that no full table scans are used?

Comment: what are you measuring, is it for example 100 sensors being polled per 'session'?

Comment: Its a scientific application - users have a slide with some cells on it. For each cell they record a number of different measurement parameters e.g. size, colour, intensity. There could be 100 cells on a slide. So each slide is a "session". There could be 100 slides in a "batch".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, as the number of calculations that needed to be carried out are not limited to just a few, I could not calculate them at the end of every measurement session.

In the end the queries did not take so long - around 3 minutes for calculating all the stats. For end users this was still an unacceptably long time to wait, BUT the good thing was that the stats did not necessarily have to be completely up to date.

Therefore I used a materialized view to take a 'snapshot' of the stats, and set it to update itself every morning at 2am. Then, when the user requested the stats from the materialized view it was instant!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that most calculations will be performed on either a single session or a single batch. If this is the case, then it's important that sessions and batches aren't distributed all over the disk.

In order to achieve the desired data clustering, you probably want to create an index-organized table (IOT) organized by batch and session. That way, the measurements belonging to the same session or same batch are close togehter on the disk and the queries for a session or batch will be limited to a small number of disk pages.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I will look into this! Another thought - when the user finished a session, I could calculate averages and standard deviations etc. for that session and save it as a row in the MEASUREMENT_SESSIONS table. This in theory would save me looking at the 100 measurement rows every time I needed one of these stats, which I guess would make the queries run faster, right?

Comment: If the possible calculations are limited, then precalculating some of them is certainly a good idea.